# Calculation did not perform to calculate the difference in total days between 2 dates in c#asp.net sql linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var query = (from m in db.Users where m.EmailAddress == emailAddress select m.Last_Login_Date).Single();

DateTime lastLoginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(query);

double diffDays = (currentDate - lastLoginDate).TotalDays;
if (diffDays < 72) {
 Security.LoginUser(u.Name, u.Role, rememberMe);
 u.Last_Login_Date = currentDate;
} else {
 Response.Redirect("ResetPwd.aspx");
}
```

I tried to perform the calculation to find the difference in total days. So if the difference is >72 days, they will be forced to do the Resetting password. But now the formula can't be performed. I think that my code have some errors. so currentDate and the db.Users Last_Login_Date are in DateTime type. Anyone has any ideas how to do the calculation, or should I change my UserDB Last_Login_Date to string type?

Comment: What is incorrect with your code?

Comment: How did you decide that there is something wrong in the code?

Comment: please include `User` class

Comment: How should we guess what you think is whong when you don´t say anything on what you expect and what you get instead?

Comment: I gave an answer, assuming that the problem was in the subtraction method. But you didn't actually gave a good information about your question. Where actually the error is happening? Or is it just not performing? This could be also happening because of ```select m.Last_Login_Date```could be null

Comment: By the way ```u.Last_Login_Date = currentDate``` in this line of code, you are changing your entity's date object, but I think you are not **updating** it in your database.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  If query doesn't return a valid date you will get an exception on following line : Convert.ToDateTime(query);

Comment: The calculation didnt perform. I default one user to have Last_Login_Date with 1/5/2019 and subtract currentDate. It goes right into the homepage without calculating the diffDays. If the calculation can run, it should response directly to ChangePwd.aspx instead of skipping the steps

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla User u = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(
                   x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress &&
                        x.Hash == Security.GetHash(password)
                        
                        );

Comment: @HowToGame, I was asking about User class structure

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[User]
 AS 
 SELECT [Id],[EmailAddress],[Name],[Hash],[DateJoined], [Last_Login_Date],'Member' AS [Role]
 FROM [Member]

 UNION
 SELECT [Id],[EmailAddress],[Name],[Hash],[DateJoined],[Last_Login_Date], 'Admin' AS [Role]
 FROM [Admin]

Answer (score 1):

Please try following:

```
//DateTime.Subtract() method will return a 'TimeSpan' value.
var timeSpan = currentDate.Subtract(lastLoginDate);
var diffDays = timeSpan.Days;

if(diffDays < 72)
{
     //Code here.
}
```

Working solution is in the below link:

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3yYxAs)

Answer (score -1):

So, I found a solution to my question. I changed to TimeSpan and it all worked now.Thanks for giving contribution.

```
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var query = (from m in db.Users
                        where m.EmailAddress == emailAddress
                        select m.Last_Login_Date).Single();
            DateTime lastLoginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(query);
            TimeSpan diffDays = currentDate.Subtract(lastLoginDate);

            if (diffDays.TotalDays> 72)
            {
                 Response.Redirect("ResetPwd.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Security.LoginUser(u.Name, u.Role, rememberMe);
                u.Last_Login_Date = currentDate;

            }
```

Comment: I did give you the exact same answer before you have posted your own. You have to accept it if it is the true answer or you shouldnt ask a question publicly. Because we spent and sacrificed our time to reproduce and find a solution to your issue.

Comment: It is good that you are trying to figure it ouy by yourself, really nice, but where exactly you are seeing the difference between ```TimeSpan diffDays = currentDate.Subtract(lastLoginDate);``` and ```var timeSpan = currentDate.Subtract(lastLoginDate);```

Comment: Yes and yet in the if(diffDays >72) , I have to put if(diffDays.totalDays > 72) in order to get the total days difference. I appreciate all of your help. Really feel grateful to have people helping me.